# Future in the past

Tags: temps-grammatical, concordance-des-temps

In English, you can say:

> I think I will do it

… which becomes the following, when put in the past:

> I thought I would do it.

How do you express the future in the past in French? Present conditional just like in English?

> J'ai pensé que je le ferais.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, conditional present is correct (*J'ai pensé que je le ferais*). There are also other possibilities, like :

> *Je pensais que j'allais le faire.*

Comment: Nice. I guess it is the exact equivalent of "I thought I was going to do it", right?

Comment: @Ricky Yes, that's it.

Comment: I think we could also shorten it to "*Je pensais le faire*".